# Is it safe to change the value of $TimeZone?

Tags: date-and-time, system-variables

I'd like to configure some of my notebooks to assume all calculations using dates, times and locations (notably `AstronomicalData` , but others too) take place at the [Greenwich Observatory](http://www.rmg.co.uk/royal-observatory/).

I know I can achieve this by unprotecting `$TimeZone` and setting it to `0`, as with

```
    $GeoLocation = {51.476786, 0.00000000};
    Unprotect[$TimeZone];
    $TimeZone = 0;
    Protect[$TimeZone];
```

but worry that this might have some other consequences that would confuse date and time functions.

Is it safe to do this? Does changing the value of `$TimeZone` have side effects I should avoid?

Comment: Can't you put it in a `Block`? In any case, I don't see any side effects, other than some date conversions and W|A calls getting messed up.

Comment: @rm-rf: Block, if you mean `Block[{$TimeZone=0}, ...]`, wasn't working for me for some functions, at least not `DateList`]. Also, I'd prefer to make the change global, rather than have to remember to make the change each time I do something that depends on it.

Comment: Why not use `TimeZone`? That's what is seems to be for. E.g. `Table[DateString[TimeZone -> i], {i, 0, 6}]` from the documentation.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: *All* calculations, *globally*. Forgetting to do that just once could really mess things up, and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @rm-rf: Hmmm... `Block` may not work, simply because `DateList` looks broken. Try `$TimeZone=0` and then `DateList[...,TimeZone->0]`. That should leave the date given unchanged, but (if you're machine timezone isn't 0) it won't. I may not even be able to do what I want with a global change of $TimeZone.

Comment: @rm-rf: It may not be possible to do what I'm trying to do here. The date and time related functions [may not work](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15733/37) quite the way they are described in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

As the Locale & Internalization guide page says `$TimeZone` is resettable.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the developers would foresee adverse effects I guess they wouldn't have documented it in this way. The only problem that I can see is that you have to take care that your system time is also set to GMT, otherwise real-time calculations (e.g., elevation of the sun as seen in Greenwich at the time of evaluation) will  give the incorrect result.