# Why do DateList, DateString, and AstronomicalData ignore $TimeZone?

Tags: curated-data, date-and-time, system-variables

My reading of the documentation for `DateList` and `DateString` lead me to believe that both functions use `$TimeZone` to determine the time zone to use in interpreting their inputs. Thus, for example, if the local machine time zone is UTC-5, `$TimeZone` is `-5`, and the time at Greenwich, corresponding to a given time in the local time zone can be found by specifying `TimeZone -> 0` as an option:

```
DateList[{2012, 10, 8, 7}, TimeZone -> 0]
{2012, 10, 8, 12, 0, 0.}

DateString[{2012, 10, 8, 7}, TimeZone -> 0]
"Mon 8 Oct 2012 12:00:00"
```

To base these calculations off a different time zone, one should simply have to change the value of `$TimeZone`, either temporarily, using `Block`, or globally, by unprotecting and [changing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15729) `$TimeZone`. But neither of these approaches works as expected. Both behave as if the *machine's time zone*, and *not* `$TimeZone` is being used to determine the local time zone:

```
Block[{$TimeZone = 0}, DateList[{2012, 10, 8, 7}, TimeZone -> 0]]
{2012, 10, 8, 12, 0, 0.}

Block[{$TimeZone = 0}, DateString[{2012, 10, 8, 7}, TimeZone -> 0]]
"Mon 8 Oct 2012 12:00:00"

(* Machine time zone is UTC-5 throughout; $TimeZone = 0 until changed below *)
Unprotect[$TimeZone]; $TimeZone = 0;

DateList[{2012, 10, 8, 7}, TimeZone -> 0]
{2012, 10, 8, 12, 0, 0.}

DateString[{2012, 10, 8, 7}, TimeZone -> 0]
"Mon 8 Oct 2012 12:00:00"
```

And even weirder:

```
DateList[{2012, 10, 8, 7}]
{2012, 10, 8, 7, 0, 0.}

DateList[{2012, 10, 8, 7}, TimeZone -> $TimeZone]
{2012, 10, 8, 12, 0, 0.}
```

And yet more [timey-wimey](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vY_Ry8J_jdw):

```
AstronomicalData["Sun", {"RightAscension", {2012, 10, 8, 7}}]
12.958492

AstronomicalData["Sun", {"RightAscension", {2012, 10, 8, 7}}, TimeZone -> 0]
12.958492

AstronomicalData["Sun", {"RightAscension", {2012, 10, 8, 7}}, TimeZone -> $TimeZone]
12.958492
```

which all seems okay until<sup>1</sup>

```
Unprotect[$TimeZone]; $TimeZone = -5

AstronomicalData["Sun", {"RightAscension", {2012, 10, 8, 7}}]
12.958492

AstronomicalData["Sun", {"RightAscension", {2012, 10, 8, 7}}, TimeZone -> 0]
12.945765

AstronomicalData["Sun", {"RightAscension", {2012, 10, 8, 7}}, TimeZone -> $TimeZone]
12.958492
```

The second set of `AstronomicalData` calculations (with `$TimeZone = -5`, the machine time zone) is at least consistent with what `DateList` and `DateString` seem to be doing: input is interpreted as being in the machine time zone (regardless of `$TimeZone`), unless a different time zone is specified using `TimeZone`. But that seems to be precisely the problem: if the time zone specified with `TimeZone` matches `$TimeZone`, it's ignored, *even if the machine time zone is different*. So in the first set of `AstronomicalData` calculations (with `$TimeZone = 0`), when `TimeZone` is '0' or `$TimeZone`, the option is just ignored, and `AstronomicalData` reports data for the default, machine time zone instead.

If `$TimeZone` is merely the default setting for `TimeZone` *options* and not the default time zones for *executing time zone dependent functions*, how do I get date and time functions to work in another time zone by default (without changing the machine's clock)?

---

<sup>1. I know the Sun's RA isn't the best value to use to spot differences over hour time scales, but since I can't get a straight answer from Wolfram (after 2 weeks of trying) about whether *Mathematica* ephemerides incorporate parallax or atmospheric effects, I wanted to be sure I had used something that would be immune to those effects when viewed from two different locations, since I don't specify those in the example.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the functions correctly

```
In[9]:= DateString[]
Out[9]= "Tue 30 Apr 2013 09:37:20"
```

while

```
In[10]:= DateString[TimeZone -> 0]
Out[10]= "Tue 30 Apr 2013 07:37:26"
```

and

```
In[33]:= AstronomicalData["Sun", {"NextRiseTime", {2012, 10, 8, 6, 0, 
   0}}, TimeZone -> 1]
Out[33]= {2012, 10, 8, 6, 35, 31.7528}

In[34]:= AstronomicalData["Sun", {"NextRiseTime", {2012, 10, 8, 6, 0, 
   0}}, TimeZone -> 4]
Out[34]= {2012, 10, 8, 9, 35, 31.722}
```

work as expected.

Comment: Can you explain how you think this addresses the question?